# Disable opening new tab using React.js while project is running

Tags: reactjs

I am developing an exam web-app using React.js, and I want that a student cannot open another tab in web browser while taking the exam

I have tried window functions but none of them is useful in this kind of situation. I can't figure out how to progress in this direction, I want to know how this can be implemented.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible with React alone, since the application runs _in_ the browser, React has no control over blocking browser functions...  You can however, open a minimum browser window  (https://superuser.com/questions/1292362/google-chrome-with-minimal-layout-without-address-bar-and-without-tabs)  but again it doesn't stop the user bypassing this with keyboard shortcuts, etc